# readlines / looping / matching string

Tags: python, python-2.7

My goal is to take two text files, read them in, identify lines in file A that need to replace the same lines in file B and be saved as file C.

I am getting stuck on how to get the specific lines from file A. I need the whole line - my searchable string is essentially the first X characters, and always starts with a :.

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

searchable_strings = (':ABC',':123',':DEF')
entries_from_a = []

app = QApplication( sys.argv )

with open( unicode ( QFileDialog.getOpenFileName() )) as file_a:
    readlines_a = file_a.read()
file_a.closed

with open( unicode ( QFileDialog.getOpenFileName() )) as file_b:
    readlines_b = file_b.read()
file_b.closed
app.quit()

for line in readlines_a:
    for item in searchable_strings:
        if item in line:
            entries_from_a.append(line)
```

- is there a totally different way to do this?
- I am using the QApplication because I want the user to select the files each time.
- Currently, nothing is ever added to entries_from_a
- On a side note, every single time I run it, I have needed to quit Spyder and open a new window to continue due to this error

  QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QPaintDevice

Comment: Your code doesn't use `readlines_b` at all. Then why do you use that?

Comment: Yet. I need to match readlines_b against the same strings and then write over those lines with the corresponding entries_from_a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Vor said you are not iterating over lines in your for loop, but over the characters of a string. `file_a.read()` returns the whole file as one string. Using for instance `readlines_a = file_a.readlines()` would return a list of the lines of `file_a`. So would using a list comprehension, which is probably the faster option and better if your files are large. Then your for loop would iterate over lines as you intend.

```
with open( unicode ( QFileDialog.getOpenFileName() )) as file_a:
    readlines_a = file_a.readlines() # readlines() method

with open( unicode ( QFileDialog.getOpenFileName() )) as file_a:
    readlines_a = [line for line in file_a] # list comprehension
```

then your for loop

Alternatively:

```
with open('filefoo') as file_a:
    with open('filebar') as file_b:
        for line in file_a:
            etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you not getting anything in `entries_from_a` is because `for line in readlines_a` reads one character at a time. And all your `searchable_strings` are more then 1 character long.

Here is an example:

```
echo "aaa\nbbb\n\ccc" > foo.txt

>>> with open('foo.txt') as f:
...   my_data = f.read()
... 
 >>> for i in my_data:
...   print i
... 
a
a
a
\
n
b
# and so on
```

So what you probably looking for is the way to iterate over each line.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call the file's `readlines` method, since the file object is an iterable object.

```
with open( unicode ( QFileDialog.getOpenFileName() )) as f:
    readlines_a = [line for line in f]

print readlines_a
```